# Mysql Where Condition on Json Type field

Tags: mysql, json

I am very much struggling in MYSQL when it comes to query JSON type column, this time I need to put where condition on a JSON type field.

JSON type value in my user table is like this: `{"id": ["2", "4"]}`

When I query a SELECT on my table like:

```
SELECT json_extract(gids, '$.id') from users
```

Its outputs like this:

```
["2", "4"]
```

I am required to write a query where I need to get all users where id=2

I have tried somthing like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE json_extract(gids, '$.id')="2"
```

But its not working, Please help on this as I am stuck here.

Thanks

Comment: `WHERE JSON_OVERLAPS(JSON_EXTRACT(gids, '$.id'), '["2"]')`?

Comment: Hey, I am getting [42000][1305] FUNCTION <DBName>.JSON_OVERLAPS does not exist, any suggestions I am having mysql 5.7 in both local and server

Comment: JSON_OVERLAPS is in MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 2):

you can try using `JSON_SEARCH` with `JSON_EXTRACT`

`JSON_SEARCH` will search data inside array.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(test, '$.id'), 'one', "1") IS NOT NULL
```

you can check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search this link for reference.

Comment: have tested this and its working fine with one Id is it possible to match multiple ids like JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(test, '$.id'), 'one', "1,2,3") IS NOT NULL

Comment: haven't tried that and not sure if that is possible 
will check about that if i can found something then will let you know about that